# Expression Blend - Create Sample Data From Class, My classes are not showing

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, expression-blend

I am trying to create sample data in my Windows Phone 8 Application.

For whatever reason, I cannot get my classes to show up when selecting 'Create Sample Data From Class'.

With 'Show All Assemblies' unchecked, I am only seeing one package (HtmlAgilityPack), when I check the check box I see many other things, but none of them are the classes from my Model directory.

Thus far I have tried rebuilding, clean build, build, restarting blend/visual studio, restarting my machine.

Why will these classes not show?

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong but according to my experience of using Expression Blend I would like to ask you.Have you tried building the solution inside Expression Blend? It should work, sometimes you compile your files in Visual Studio but they need to get compiled in Expression Blend IDE. CTRL+ Shift+ B , just build it and I hope it would solve your issue.